# Why is this code giving me an error when I enter a number with comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = int(input("Write the first number: "))

y = int(input("Write the second number: "))
```

Comment: because comma is not an integer ?

Comment: Integers in Python don't contain commas. Integers as a string can for formatting purposes, but when attempting to set the value of a variable to an integer, you'd have to remove the commas.

Answer (score 1):

Integers don't include commas, so if you want to be able to enter a number with commas you need to strip them out before converting the string to an int. For example, `x = int(input("Write the first number: ").replace(',',''))` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to accept the input separating the comma

```
x,y=map(int,input('Enter two numbers seperated by comma').split(','))
```